# Permission denied when pushing docker image on cloud run

Tags: docker, configuration, google-cloud-storage, push, permission-denied

I contact you because I am stuck since 2 days trying to push my work on google cloud run.

When I enter the command : `docker push $MULTI_REGION/$PROJECT/$IMAGE`

The result is :

```
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [eu.gcr.io/le-wagon-ds/image-name]
b028f6321f0b: Preparing 
f0049b6a2a38: Preparing 
e4105b8f307b: Preparing 
292a2a280e93: Preparing 
bacec458bca2: Preparing 
ddd6db8a3bdc: Waiting 
75b1484c54ef: Waiting 
b2fa61b044ea: Waiting 
aee88de63e6f: Waiting 
13e8b36cbbec: Waiting 
821bf6371720: Waiting 
8d3476a52917: Waiting 
40572195ea84: Waiting 
024595e1462f: Waiting 
denied: Token exchange failed for project 'le-wagon-ds'. Caller does not have permission 'storage.buckets.create'. To configure permissions, follow instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control
```

And unfortunately, the push failed... So I went in 'Service Account section', then 'permission' and I gave almost all the permissions to my principal 'demange.louis@hotmail.fr', that's to say :

- Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension
- Editor
- Owner
- Security Admin
- Security Reviewer
- Service Account Token Creator
- Velostrata Manager
- Viewer

But it is not possible to give 'storage administrator' as I need.

I checked well in my terminal with `gcloud auth list` that 'demange.louis@hotmail.fr' was indeed the principal being used when trying to push the work.

I precise that I didn't create bucket because I don't think it is necessary to push my work. If you have an idea of the problem, please write me ! :) . I precise that I am new on gcp, so my knowledge is really limited at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Louis Demange

Comment: See [Authentication Methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication). Your authenticating to `gcloud` as `demange.louis@hotmail.fr` **but** to use `docker push`, `docker` needs to be able to provide same|similiar credentials to Google (Container Registry). The document explains how to do this. The preferred method is the credential helper.

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions but it didn't work and I was not able to figure out what was wrong. Have you an idea to debug it step by step ? (test/check the result). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't go to the service account section, only the IAM section (project level), and add the storage admin role

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get it to work although my permissions for demange.louis@hotmail.fr in IAM section are :
-Owner
-Storage Admin
-Storage Object Admin
-Storage Object Creator

Comment: My problem is solved : I put the name of a project that didn't exist and not the good one. But the error message was very misleading... Thanks you again !